# WCF Custom Authentication with more than 2 parameters

Tags: c#, wcf

```
public class Authentication : UserNamePasswordValidator
{

   public override void Validate(string userName, string password, string companyID)
   { 

     //How can i pass a custom data like "companyID" to Validate method ?
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If *companyID* is identifier from client then possible easiest way is pass it as a part of userName:

```
//on client:
string username = companyID + ":" + realUsername;
```

and just split in validator:

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password) {
    string companyID, realUsername;
    string[] parts = userName.Split(':', 2);
    if (parts.Length == 2) {
        companyID = parts[0];
        realUsername = parts[1];
    }
}
```